# Deploying configuration via Jenkinsfile to unknown amount of servers

Tags: jenkins, deployment, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, cloud

We're setting up multiple more or less static servers in AWS. These are primarily configured via Ansible and that's also the ultimate source of truth when it comes to their existence, grouping, host names and IPs. But then there's Jenkins deploying configuration files to these servers based on new commits added to a git repository.

I'm having an issue with listing the target servers directly in a Jenkinsfile. How shall I proceed? Which are the most common ways of dealing with this?

I understand this is mostly an opinion based topic. But maybe there's a particular Jenkins feature which I don't know about...?

Thank you.

Comment: If you forget about Jenkins. How do you currently store/retrieve these details?

Comment: @ycr Ansible hostfile.
Currently I'm trying to get the list of eligible EC2 hosts from an ELBv2 target group. That looks promising.

Comment: Well then use your Ansible inventory from Jenkins in an Ansible job.

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective. Following are a few ways to do this.

1. Store the details somewhere accessible after the Ansible step. Possibly commit to a Github repo and retrieve these details within the Jenkins Job.
2. Using AWS APIs/CLI to retrieve server details. You can either set up AWS CLI in Jenkins Agent or use something like [AWS Step Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin).
3. Do an API call to Jenkins after the Ansible script is executed and update the server details in the Job itself.

Comment: ... or use the existing Ansible inventory in an Ansible job inside Jenkins.